# Python 2.7 & exported 1 Selenium IDE script = Blank Firefox Page - Why?

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium

I'm attempting to execute 1 test script (exported from `Selenium IDE 3.4` where it runs fine) from `Python 2.7` with Firefox 53.03 (64 bit) and Geckodriver 0.16. on my local machine - Windows 7 Enterprise.

Steps to Reproduce:

1. From Selenium IDE: Export Test Case As 'Python 2/unittest /WebDriver'.
2. Saved as 'Search by Vol & Folio - Unsuccessful.py'
3. Launched Python 2.7.12 Shell
4. File / Open / 'Search by Vol & Folio - Unsuccessful.py'
5. Run / Run Module

Results in:

cmd sessions opens with `Geckodriver.exe` + Blank Firefox page

Error message from Python console is:

> Python 2.7.12 (v2.7.12:d33e0cf91556, Jun 27 2016, 15:24:40) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>   Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>    RESTART: C:\Temp\Selenium\selenium-java-3.4.0\Search by Vol & Folio - Unsuccessful.py
>
> ====================================================================== ERROR: test_search_by_vol_folio_unsuccessful_cancel
>   (**main**.SearchByVolFolioUnsuccessfulCancel)
>   ---------------------------------------------------------------------- Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Temp\Selenium\selenium-java-3.4.0\Search by Vol & Folio -
>   Unsuccessful.py", line 13, in setUp
>       self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()   File "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Python\2.7\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py",
>   line 155, in **init**
>       keep_alive=True)   File "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Python\2.7\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 92, in **init**
>       self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)   File "C:\Program Files\Common
>   Files\Python\2.7\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 183, in start_session
>       self.capabilities = response['value'] KeyError: 'value'
>
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------- Ran 1 test in 5.250s
>
> FAILED (errors=1)

Comment: Can you consider showing us your work please? I think your question have no relation to `selenium` which deals with `webdrivers` but it relates to `selenium-ide`. Please confirm. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear there problem came from.

```
 self.capabilities = response['value']
```

but `response` not have key `value`